# React & Webpack Dev Server: Hot Reloading not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've got a React app with a fairly simple Webpack setup, I'm wanting to use Webpack Dev Server and enable Hot Reloading. It feels like I've read nearly all answers for solving this...

**package.json**

`"dev": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --open --progress --mode development --content-base dist --config webpack.dev.js",`

**webpack.common.js**

```
devtool: "source-map",
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    "./src/client/index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/"
  }
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    index: "index.html",
    stats: "normal",
    inline: true,
    clientLogLevel: "info"
  },
  mode: "development"
});
```

To run the project, I run `yarn run dev` and it will load the webpack-dev-server and open the React app in the browser, however, it doesn't hot reload. I'm not sure if it re-builds the bundle.js file, because when re-freshing the browser, it still loads the old version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the static configured page. Static bundle is the file on your disk and it is recreated after you run webpack build command. You will use static configuration in production when it is ready to release.

You need to load dynamic bundle wich is server from webpack virtual file systems and which is accessible from url where webpack dev server is binded. For example `http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js`. This will be updated by webpack dev server each time when sources is changed.

Comment: That makes sense, are any obvious fixes that I can make to allow for Hot Reloading with my current config?

Comment: Check which port is used by webpack dev serv. Navigate to localhost:port/ or add path to bundle. Check that your html is also accessible there. Make sure that your html refer to correct bundle url.

Comment: The answer in the end was that my webpack bundle had a wrong output path, so after I changed that it worked

Comment: This mean exactly that your html must refer to correct url to the dinamic bundle. There is no difference how it was done, by changing output path or by carefully setting up url in html.

Answer (score 0):

While hot module reloading might be enabled in webpack, it also require some changes in codebase, have you used `module.hot` in your application? (https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr take a look at index.js part). As a react-specific alternative, [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#getting-started) can be used